How to quantify the stability of an optimization to compare different sets of basis functions?
I'm minimizing some value stochastically (Monte Carlo methods) using different sets of basis functions to fit some unknown function needed to calculate this value. The dimensionality of the parameter space is around 100 to 500 of optimizable parameters. The optimization method used is the Newton-Raphson optimization with stochastically calculated gradient and Hessian (with some stabilization using an identity matrix if the Hessian is not positive-definite). I'm observing that some sets of basis functions converge better to global minima than others. Possible convergence problems are the existence of local minima or too large proposed steps during the minimization.
I know that there are better optimization methods than the one I'm using (e.g., trust-region methods), but I compare the sets of basis functions in terms of their robustness.
I already investigated the eigenvalues of the Hessians in the seeming minima (obtained
in the case of little change of the value between the iterations) for different sets of basis functions and found out that better performing sets have generally greater eigenvalues (and are greater than the statistical error). But I don't know the reason for this. Also this points aren't the real minima for worse performing sets because the gradients in this points are not zero (i.e., are not within the statistical error). Therefore, this investigation is not consistent for all compared sets.
As far as I know, orthogonal polynomials are numerically more stable than simple powers of the parameter ($1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots$) for fitting of one-dimensional functions. But I have never seen a way to quantify the difference.
I also investigated the sets of basis functions on near linear dependence by defining the scalar product between two basis functions ($\langle f, g \rangle = \int_D f(x) g(x) \mathrm{d} x$) and calculating the angle between them ($\arccos \left( \langle f, g \rangle / \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle \langle g, g \rangle} \right)$). However, I haven't found any definite correlation between the orthogonality and optimization stability.
Is there a way to quantify the stability of optimization to compare different sets of used basis functions?
